# Functions and methods for working with AST tree

Tags: idapython, hexrays

I am implementing deep search with Python Hex Ray API.
Can someone say classes and methods for implementing this feature with the IDA Python API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hex-Rays’ version of AST is called “ctree”, so you can search for the term in `hexrays.hpp` to see what methods are available, as well as in the sample plugins and scripts.